# Matlab: how to create random points and rotate them so that all values are negative

Tags: matlab

I want to create random points which are in the first quadrant

```
IV   I
III  II
```

and after rotating 270° they are in the III quadrant.

```
coords = 100;
x1 = randperm(coords);
x2 = randperm(coords);


y = zeros(2, coords);

for point = 1:coords
    y = rot(270) * x;
end
```

Still, the last if condition proofs the opposite the alle coords are negative. What I have to change?

Comment: You mean rotating 180°? You can achieve that by negating x and y.

Comment: thanks that worked ! late night-working xD